# MySQL encoding of an image into html

Tags: python, mysql

simply, I want to fetch all 156 stored images in database and produce an html link such as "`<img src ...../> "`

My code works great at extracting the image from the database and viewing them. but when I started testing base64 encoding, I receive the following error.

```
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

here is the code:

```
import MySQLdb
import base64
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="test",         # your username
                     passwd="test",  # your password
                     db="test")
cur = db.cursor()


cur.execute("SELECT * FROM attachments")

#looping through row 4 where all blobs are located

for row in cur.fetchall():
    blob_read = row[4]

#(error happen here while decoding)

    decoding = blob_read.decode('base64')
    print '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,"'+ decoding + '/>'

    filename = row[2]

#(extracted the files to test if images are corrupted; they are not)

       with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(blob_read)

db.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a cup of coffee did the job =D 
I peeked at the database again, and found the attachments table did not only have pictures, but rather in html/text, image/jpeg,video/3gpp, audio/amr. hence, it explains the error above.

So I tweaked the script by adding another loop of only deal with image/jpeg

here is the solution without cleaning up etc

```
import MySQLdb
import base64
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="test",         # your username
                     passwd="test",  # your password
                     db="test")
cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM attachments")
count = 0

for row in cur.fetchall():
        if row[1] == "image/jpeg":
            blob_read = row[4]
            image = blob_read
            output = base64.encodestring(image)
            print output
            print 
            print
            print "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            print 
            print 
            filename = row[2]
            with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
                output_file.write(blob_read)
                count = count + 1 
        else:
            pass




print count

db.close()
```